# Bash pip search checking version is contained in standard out

Tags: bash, pip

I am trying to do a pip search.

```
pip search --index https://obfuscated/python-release docker-client
```

This returns 
`docker-client (1.3.0)  - Client library for Docker Pipeline - 0f7f2d821d09db2f268281c84e298967a6df4b11`

I want to be able to search that output string to match the versions in my bash script. For example I would want to grep that standard out to make sure that it is indeed version 1.3.0. How would I go about doing in this in the bash script below.

```
set -e
if pip search --index https://obfuscated/python-release docker-client; then
    echo " hello world"
fi
`));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do:

```
#!/bin/bash

version='1.3.0'

if [ $(pip search --index https://obfuscated/python-release docker-client | grep -c $version) -eq 1 ]
then
    echo "OK version $version it is."
else
    echo "ERROR: pip failure, or wrong version."
fi
```

Obviously this will work if version numbers do not appear all over the place.  Ex. if `pip` returned `( 1.3.4, upgrade from 1.3.0 )` it would not work.  You will have to work around output format, but based on what you provided, this will work.